# centering a div is not working

Tags: html, css

I did the magic trick to center a div by giving it a `margin:--px auto` but it does not work. what could be the issue here?

https://jsfiddle.net/1zptxa7h/3/

```
<div class="single-view-container" style="display: block;">
     <div id="single-view" class="single-view grid-100 grid-parent">center me</div>
</div>

  .single-view-container {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 3;
      overflow: auto;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      display: none;}

  .single-view {
      color: white;
      max-width: 100px;
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 20px auto;
      height:100px;
      background:red;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
      border-radius: 2px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: Nope, no magic, just [`text-align:center;`](https://jsfiddle.net/1zptxa7h/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `margin: 0 auto` work on block elements with a fixed width, so if you change to `display: block` (or remove it completely as it is the default for a `div`) it will work as expected.

*Side note: If to center an `inline` element (or `inline-block`), set `text-align: center` on its parent.*

```css
  .single-view-container {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 3;
      overflow: auto;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      display: none;}

  .single-view {
      color: white;
      max-width: 100px;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      margin: 20px auto;
      height:100px;
      background:red;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
      border-radius: 2px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="single-view-container" style="display: block;">
     <div id="single-view" class="single-view grid-100 grid-parent">center me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change an element to `display: inline-block` margin auto no longer works as it's an inline element you need to make its parent am have `text-align: center;`

```
.single-view-container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your css .single-view with this:

```
.single-view {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LwmLjumu/1/).

Add,

```
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="single-view-container" style="display: block;">
     <div id="single-view" class="single-view grid-100 grid-parent">center me</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.single-view-container {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 3;
      overflow: auto;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      display: none;}

  .single-view {
      color: white;
      max-width: 100px;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 20px auto;
      height:100px;
      background:red;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
      border-radius: 2px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      text-align:center;
      display:block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Centered.

```css
#single-view {
  width:200px;
  background: green;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
  <div id="single-view">center me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap? Put in your element "text-center" to center it.

```
<div class="single-view-container text-center" style="display: block;">
  <div id="single-view" class="single-view grid-100 grid-parent">center me</div>
</div>
```